# subset a certain part of my data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

Suppose I have a data.frame that looks something like this:

```
ball1  ball2  ball3  allRed 
 red    red   blue     F
 red    red    red     T
 blue   blue   red     F
  .      .      .      .
  .      .      .      .
  .      .      .      .
```

And so on. I wish to extract the first 5 rows of the data frame in which allRed are TRUE, and the first 5 rows of the data.frame in which allRed are FALSE. I stored the data.frame in a variable `ball`.  Below is what I had tried to little avail:

```
ball[,1][ball$allRed==F]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
head(ball[ball$allRed, ], 5)
```

will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You should subset `allRed` first, and then 5 rows from that. Also, pay attention to your commas. Try:

```
ball[ball$allRed == TRUE, ][1:5, ]
```